# Xamarin Forms' WebView - local assets not found on Windows Phone

Tags: xamarin, webview, windows-phone-8.1, xamarin.forms

I'm using WebView to display HTML from a string. This HTML references a stylesheet that I have locally on the device. I'm following the instructions from [the official docs](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/user-interface/webview/#Local_HTML_Content) so the local CSS file can be accessed. It works fine on Android and iOS but I can't make it work on Windows Phone 8.1. I placed the CSS file in the root of the project and set the build action to **Content**, then set the BaseUrl to `""` (I tried `ms-appx-web:///` as well, with no success).

Does anyone know if the docs are missing some instructions? Or is it a bug in Forms? Any help would be appreciated.

Here's the code for populating the WebView with data (in a Forms PCL):

```
private async Task LoadData()
{
    string html = await _dataProvider.GetHtmlAsync("index");
    WebView.Source = new HtmlWebViewSource
    {
        Html = html,
        BaseUrl = _baseUrlProvider.Get()
    };
}
```

`_baseUrlProvider` is an instance of my `WebViewBaseUrlProvider` that is defined as follows:

```
internal class WebViewBaseUrlProvider : IWebViewBaseUrlProvider
{
    public string Get() => "";
}
```

---

**EDIT:**

Seeing [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36843819/webview-baseurl-in-xamarin-forms-on-uwp-and-windows-phone-8-1?rq=1) leads me to believe that there indeed is a bug in Xamarin Forms. When the link in the HTML contains the whole `ms-appx-web:///style.css` instead of just `style.css`, it suddenly starts to work. Obviously, this is not quite cross-platform...

Comment: can you please share your complete code written for loading html file?

Comment: see this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39090445/visual-studio-2015-wont-display-local-web-page-ms-appx/39198818#39198818

Comment: Sure, I just edited the question. The answer you mentioned is valid for Universal App. I'm targeting Windows Phone 8.1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just found the answer - Xamarin simply ignores the BaseUrl property: https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/blob/2d9288eee6e6f197364a64308183725e7bd561f9/Xamarin.Forms.Platform.WinRT/WebViewRenderer.cs#L26